# Postgres make spaces with ''::text statement

Tags: postgresql, casting, concatenation, postgresql-9.3

Does anyone know why Postgresql 9.3.17 do this with concat() function ?

If I do :

`SELECT concat(tab.a::text, ' '::text, tab.b::text) AS field FROM schem.tab`

I'll have "a b" with 3 spaces (one in the ' ' and two added by Postgres)

If I do:

`SELECT concat(concat(tab.a::text, ' '::text), tab.b::text) AS field FROM schem.tab`

I'll have "a b" with my only space

Comment: Can you show the problem on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ ? If I try what you put in your question, with "a" in column `a` and "b" in column `b`, I don't see any additional spaces.

Comment: Why are you using `' '::text` in the first place?  The `' '` is already a text string literal.

Comment: Yeah and the concat() don't need any cast before but when a write a query for a view Postgres add it automaticaly and it's screwing the data. If i do this select concat('abcde', to_char(2, '9'), NULL, 22::text) it'll add a space between element 0 and 1

Comment: @kero `concat('abcde', ' 2')` gives `'abcde 2'`, but that single space is there because it is present in element 1. In your case, the question should be "Why does `to_char(2, '9')` give `' 2'` instead of `'2'`?" (That is covered in [the documentation for `to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html), by the way.)